# What do "m" and "k" mean in "m >>= k"?

Tags: haskell, monads

The notation `m >>= k` is sometimes used in examples of the Haskell bind function (`>>=`). Do `m` and `k` have any conventional meanings? Why are these particular letters selected? Based on what `k` does, I am guessing that `k` means "continuation", but what is `m`?

Comment: Perhaps "value having a _monadic_ type". Hard to tell for sure.

Comment: I've always assumed `m` was used for a monadic value (ie a value whose type is `m a` for some monad `m` and concrete type `a`). No idea about `k`. (But then I've rarely seem that, I would use `m >>= f` myself, which emphasises - or at least hints - that the second argument is a function.)

Comment: Have you considered they don't necessarily have a particular meaning? Maybe they were chosen because these letters were "available".

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, `m`/`M` is usually short for one of monadic, `Map` and friends, mutable, or `Maybe` (roughly in order of popularity). Meanwhile `k` is usually short for key, short for a misspelling of continuation, or the iteration variable in a deeply nested loop (again roughly in popularity order).  Given the `(>>=)` context, "monadic" and "continuation" seem most likely.